# Sync and Async problem. System.aggregateexception 'one or more errors occurred.' when I try to get a list of objects from an URL

Tags: c#, asynchronous, synchronization, timeout, task

So, I am trying to get a json with a list of movies from tmdb and for that I've created the methods down here. The problem is that if a run it syncronously it gave me TimeOut.

```
public void getMovieInfo(string kWord)
        {

            using (WebClient web = new WebClient())
            {
                string url = string.Format("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?page=1&api_key=" + apiKey + "&query=" + kWord);

                var json = web.DownloadString(url);



                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonExtract.root>(json);
                JsonExtract.root outPut = result;


                movies.Clear();
                int accesIndex = 0;
                while (outPut.results != null)
                {
                    movies.Add(outPut.results[accesIndex++].title);
                }
            }
        }
```

If I return a Task.Result

```
public async Task<string> getMovieInfoAsync(string kWord)
        {

            using (WebClient web = new WebClient())
            {
                string url = string.Format("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?page=1&api_key=" + apiKey + "&query=" + kWord);

                var json = web.DownloadString(url);



                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonExtract.root>(json);
                JsonExtract.root outPut = result;


                movies.Clear();
                int accesIndex = 0;
                while (outPut.results != null)
                {
                    movies.Add(outPut.results[accesIndex++].title);
                }
            }
```

And calling like this it work but freeze for like 3 seconds on first call

```
getMovieInfoAsync(keyword);
```

And if a calling like this it gave me 'System.aggregateexception 'one or more errors occurred.'

```
Task<string> task = Task.Run(async () => await getMovieInfoAsync(keyword));
task.Wait();
movies = task.Result;
```

I've search and tryed bunch of hours for a solution but didn't succeed yet.
Can sameone give me any pointers of why is this happening, or can explain me what do I do wrong. 
Thank you

Comment: The 2nd snippet does not compile. Is there something missing? A `return` probably?

Comment: By the way, if you go async, go async "all the way". Mixing sync and async is a _really_ bad idea.

Comment: If you get an AggregateException, you need to look into the inner Exception of it. I'd expect to find a ... TimeOut.

Comment: The ideea was not to mix them, is that i tried them both call and they behave async both

Answer (score 0):

Simply returning a `Task` does not make your method asynchronous.

Doing this:

```
var json = web.DownloadString(url);
```

is still going to block the thread until you have a HTTP response.

`WebClient` is a pre-async technology, and `DownloadString` is a **synchronous** method.

I would have a look at `HttpClient` instead, which has much better async support:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
{
    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

The use of the `async` keyword will free up the thread until you have your response.

Your second example using `Task.Run` is a workaround that shouldn't be necessary, but if you check the inner exception, you should have a better idea.

Comment: Just to clarify: using `async` *and* awaiting an actually-asynchronous operation will free up the thread until you have a response. Using `async` alone does not do anything useful, neither does using `await` with an already-completed `Task`.